# Swift: Always getting the least recent item from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

My goal is to build a simple app which:

- Has `UITableViewCell`s by fetching items from `Firebase`.
- Each cell performs a segue to another `ViewController` when tapped.
- Shows further details of the fetched items in the presented `ViewController`.

With the work I've done so far:

- I can successfully fetch data from the database and put it in a dictionary. I am also able to populate `UITableViewCell`s based on this data.
- Cells presents a new `ViewController` as desired when tapped.

The problem is, regardless of the cell I tap, my `ViewController` always presents the least recently added item from `Firebase` database. Let me provide my database structure and my Swift code:

**Firebase structure:**

```
simple-app:
└── upcoming:
    └── fourth:
        └── desc: "description for the fourth item"
        └── name: "fourth item"
    └── third:
        └── desc: "description for the third item"
        └── name: "third item"
    └── second:
        └── desc: "description for the second item"
        └── name: "second item"
    └── first:
        └── desc: "description for the first item"
        └── name: "first item"
```

**Swift code:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class Upcoming: UITableViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var upcomingItems: UITableView!
    var itemName: String?
    var itemDesc: String?

    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var refHandle: UInt!

    var itemList = [Item]()
    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        fetchItems()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
        itemName = itemList[indexPath.row].name
        itemDesc = itemList[indexPath.row].desc

        cell.textLabel?.text = itemName
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailedInfo", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "DetailedInfo" {
            var vc = segue.destination as! DetailedInfo
            vc.name = itemName
            vc.desc = itemDesc
        }
    }

    func fetchItems(){
        refHandle = ref.child("upcoming").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                print(dictionary) // dictionary is as desired, no corruption
                let item = Item()
                item.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                self.itemList.append(token)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I can see four different cells with four different names as desired, but no matter which cell is tapped, next `ViewController` shows `name` and `desc` values of the least recently added item, which is `first`, from the database. Any idea is appreciated to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

itemName and itemDesc will always be the last cell because you write it in cellForRow, 
set the items in didSelectRow

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
        cell.textLabel?.text = itemList[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        itemName = itemList[indexPath.row].name
        itemDesc = itemList[indexPath.row].desc
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailedInfo", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this approach

```
refHandle = ref.child("upcoming").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

But this is the case if there is no need to constantly check the database updates.

Comment: Can't give this a try, I am receiving the following error: "Cannot assign value of type 'Void' to type 'UInt!'"